# How to install sudokumaker from pypi?

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv, pypi

I want to utilize [sudokumaker 0.2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sudokumaker/0.2) in my Django app. But I cannot install this package. How can I install it?

I tried the following:

```
virtualenv '/path_to/project' -p /usr/bin/python2.7
sudo pip install sudokumaker
```

and

```
sudo pip install sudokumaker-0.2
```

Comment: Can you run `pip` without `sudo` and update your question with the error message?

Comment: Do you even have `pip` installed? You can check by running `pip -V`

Comment: @RetoAebersold here, the same message with and without sudo : `Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement sudokumaker
  No distributions at all found for sudokumaker`. Probably the package name is wrong, but how do I find the correct name?

Comment: @mevius yes pip is installed. pip -V output is : `pip 6.0.8 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)`

Comment: Weird...it even shows up if you do `pip search sudokumaker`...No idea what the problem is, but I can't install it either.

Comment: @mevius is it possible that the owner of the package has somehow disabled it for downloading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you don't use sudo, once you have a virtual environment setup:

```
virtualenv /path/to/virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7
source /path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate
(virtualenv) $ pip install sudokumaker
```

However this package has not published any releases; until the author does so pip won't be able to install anything.

To install it, you'll have to [download the source from sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sudokumaker/files/latest/download); expand the archive and then manually install it:

```
$ virtualenv sudoku
New python executable in sudoku/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
$ source sudoku/bin/activate
(sudoku)$ tar xvzf ~/Downloads/sudokumaker-0.4.tar.gz 
sudokumaker-0.4/
sudokumaker-0.4/PKG-INFO
sudokumaker-0.4/setup.py
sudokumaker-0.4/maker.py
sudokumaker-0.4/README.html
sudokumaker-0.4/sudoku_as_tex
sudokumaker-0.4/sudoku.py
sudokumaker-0.4/Version.py
sudokumaker-0.4/README.rst
sudokumaker-0.4/sudokumaker
sudokumaker-0.4/__init__.py
(sudoku)burhan@T530 ~ $ cd sudokumaker-0.4/
(sudoku)burhan@T530 ~/sudokumaker-0.4 $ python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sudokumaker
copying Version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sudokumaker
copying maker.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sudokumaker
copying sudoku.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sudokumaker
copying __init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sudokumaker
running build_scripts
creating build/scripts-2.7
copying and adjusting sudoku_as_tex -> build/scripts-2.7
copying and adjusting sudokumaker -> build/scripts-2.7
changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/sudoku_as_tex from 644 to 755
changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/sudokumaker from 644 to 755
running install_lib
creating /home/burhan/sudoku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sudokumaker
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sudokumaker/Version.py -> /home/burhan/sudoku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sudokumaker
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sudokumaker/maker.py -> /home/burhan/sudoku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sudokumaker
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sudokumaker/sudoku.py -> /home/burhan/sudoku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sudokumaker
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/sudokumaker/__init__.py -> /home/burhan/sudoku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sudokumaker
byte-compiling /home/burhan/sudoku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sudokumaker/Version.py to Version.pyc
byte-compiling /home/burhan/sudoku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sudokumaker/maker.py to maker.pyc
byte-compiling /home/burhan/sudoku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sudokumaker/sudoku.py to sudoku.pyc
byte-compiling /home/burhan/sudoku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sudokumaker/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
running install_scripts
copying build/scripts-2.7/sudoku_as_tex -> /home/burhan/sudoku/bin
copying build/scripts-2.7/sudokumaker -> /home/burhan/sudoku/bin
changing mode of /home/burhan/sudoku/bin/sudoku_as_tex to 755
changing mode of /home/burhan/sudoku/bin/sudokumaker to 755
running install_egg_info
Writing /home/burhan/sudoku/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sudokumaker-0.4-py2.7.egg-info
```

You will also need to download and [rsclib](http://rsclib.sourceforge.net/) - again, manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
python -m pip install sudokumaker
```

or

```
python2 -m pip install sudokumaker
```

To install the python package. The package definitly exists: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sudokumaker